# Regex to validate letters and numbers doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression that contains 17 characters, must have mandatory numbers and letters, and must not contain the letters I, O, Q, Ñ. At the moment I have got:

```
^(([a-h]|[j-n]|p|[r-z]|[A-H]|[J-N]|P|[R-Z]|[0-9]){17})$
```

But if I type only numbers or only letters, the regular expression validates it as good.

Comment: It's not completely clear from your description, but are you saying that you want to accept all of the letters in your existing regex, plus digits, and that BOTH letters and digits must be present?

Comment: JohnJ, plus digit can be used

Comment: I need exactly to validate a VIM (Vehicle Identification Number) it contents digits and letters, not content I, O, Q, Ñ, and obligatory 17 characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally in such cases you want to use [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in order to assert that the input satisfies additional conditions. Since you have two conditions here (must contain at least one number, must contain at least one letter), this translates to two different lookaheads.

Together with extra whitespace and "comments" for readability the regex should look like this:

```
^
(?=.*[a-hj-npr-zA-HJ-NPR-Z].*)  // assert the input contains at least one letter
(?=.*[0-9].*)                   // assert the input contains at least one digit
[a-hj-npr-zA-HJ-NPR-Z0-9]{17}   // existing condition (17 allowed chars exactly)
$
```

Answer (score 3):

Use positive and negative look-aheads to require and disallow characters:

```
/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?!.*[ioqñIOQÑ])[0-9a-zA-Z]{17}$/.test(s);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2mNyg/

Description:

```
(?=.*[0-9])        - requires a digit
(?=.*[A-Za-z])     - requires a letter
(?!.*[ioqñIOQÑ])   - disallows all characters in the set
[0-9a-zA-Z]{17}    - allow basic set and require 17 characters
```

Note: The look-ahead that requires a letter will also be satisfied by the disallowed characters, but the look-ahead that disallows the characters will still stop it. That way you can make the expression simpler.

Comment: Like! I only went half way... :)